# Openpyxl: can't seem to get the syntax right for what I'm trying to do (read next cell down)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Here's the code I have. I'm simply trying to open a spreadsheet (which currently only has information in the first column), and read the first cell, print the information, then later along the lines loop back up to the top and read the next cell down. What am I doing wrong?

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('students2.xlsx')

ws = wb.active

PrintNext = True #Starts my while statement
while True :

    for i in range(1,300):        #I think this is where I'm having an issue?
        for j in range(1,2):
            StudentID = ws.cell(row=i+1, column=j).value

    print(StudentID)
    PrintNext = False        #This gets it to move on from my while
    pass

PrintNext = True       #This is to get it to go back to my while
print(StudentID)       #This is to test that it has the next cell down
```

I found the solution with the help of the answer here, but I found a much better solution over-all.

Set these to variables:

```
for i in range(RowX,RowY):
    for j in range(ColX,ColY):
        StudentID = ws.cell(row=i+1, column=j).value
```

So that any changes you make ("RowX = RowX + 1", for example) are reflected the next time you update the "for" statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [cell.offset()](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.cell.interface.html?highlight=offset) method.

Comment: Here is the code I ended up with:

                `print(StudentID)
                PrintNext = False

                class AbstractCell(ABC):
                    @abstractmethod
                    def offset(self, row=1, column=0):
                        pass`

Comment: I don't understand that code. Much better to edit your original question.

Comment: Roger that! Updated!